# Room Update Multiple Fields

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, android-room, android-architecture-components

I would like to update some fields from `table 1` to be the same as the values from another `table` (or even a subquery). The issue is I get a `compilation error` in my `DAO` update query when there is more than 1 field.

You can see the code (rewritten to be generic) below:

```sql
@Query("UPDATE table1 " +
     " SET (field1, field2) = " +
     " (SELECT SUM(table2.foreign_field1) as summaryForeign_field1, table2.foreign_field2 " +
     " FROM table2 " +
     " WHERE   table1.id = table2.id " + 
     " GROUP BY table2.foreign_field2 ) ")
void setFieldsInTable1();
```

I checked the query with the notes in [SQLite Update Query Ref](https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#row_values_in_update_statements) and I have tried the code in `DB Browser` for `SQLite` where it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? post the error log

Comment: I get:    <Column name> expected, got '('

Comment: @KaranMer, just wondering if you managed to recreate the issue? It seems the line where i've bracketed the 2 fields i would like to update is what is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot a `+` on line 4**.

If this is just a copy/past error then there must be something wrong in your original query that you removed when you tried to make it generic for your question.

This should work, here is a working example :

[Online example](http://tpcg.io/MDsPOX)

Code :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create tables */
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 text,
    field2 text
);

CREATE TABLE table2(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 text,
    foreign_field1 integer,
    FOREIGN KEY(foreign_field1) REFERENCES table1(id)
);

/* Create few records */
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,'Tom', 'French');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(2,'Lucy', 'American');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(3,'Frank', 'English');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(4,'Jane', 'Polish');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(5,'Robert', 'French');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,'Monday', 3);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(2,'Wednesday', 5);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(3,'Friday', 1);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(4,'Tuesday', 4);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(5,'Monday', 1);

COMMIT;

/* Display records from the table1 */
SELECT * FROM table1;

/* Update records from table1 */
UPDATE table1 
SET (field1, field2) = (
    SELECT
        SUM(table2.foreign_field1) as summaryForeign_field1,
        table2.field1 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id 
    GROUP BY table2.field1
);

/* Check that the update has been executed correctly */
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

So maybe try to build an online minimal example closer to your original query.

**EDIT** : OK as per your comment I have tested and can reproduce the problem in my project, indeed it does not compile, error is :

> error: no viable alternative at input 'update test SET (name,'
>   extraneous input ')' expecting {, ';', ',', '=', '*', '+', '-',
>   '||', '/', '%', '<<', '>>', '&', '|', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==',
>   '!=', '<>', ...}

Unfortunately I think this is a Room limitation. Maybe you can submit an issue to Google to get more info about this.

Meanwhile, you can try with [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery) (as stated in the doc it MUST return a non-void type but you can return a fake string or empty POJO for example) :

```
@RawQuery
String setFieldsInTable1(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

Then use it like this :

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("UPDATE table1 SET ...");
yourDao.setFieldsInTable1(query);
```

Another solution is to just go with 2 subqueries this way :

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = (
    SELECT SUM(table2.foreign_field1)
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id
    GROUP BY table2.foreign_field2
),
field2 = (
    SELECT table2.foreign_field2
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id
);
```

Also depending on your application workflow, you can modify your entity in your code and then use the `Update` interface to update it:

```
@Update
void update(Table1Entity... table1Entities);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yann39, unfortunately that was just a copy and paste error (edited the question to correct it now). I see that your code was executed in an SQLite edittor and you are correct that it works there. My issue is for some reason in Android when using Room, I am trying to replicate this in my DAO and it is not allowing me to have brackets to set the 2 fields - this line: "SET (field1, field2) =" is giving me an error

Comment: OK you're right I can reproduce the problem, I have updated my answer. It seems to be a Room limitation, but can't find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Great to see it wasn't just me being dumb. I will log it with Google. I didn't think it would be right to perform multiple update queries for the fields (there are more than 2 in my real code), so I used the RAWQUERY you pointed out. Just for the sake of others who may use this method though, can you edit the answer to show that a RawQuery needs to return a type. So I just used a String, and as my update query doesn't return anything this String is always null - which doesn't affect my code. Thanks again :)